# Email information of Child Object while creating Parent object Record

Tags: email-template, quickaction

We have two Custom Object having MD relationship

1. Query (Parent)
2. Questions (Child)

Now, we have created a record for Query (Parent) and added multiple questions in Questions Object(child).

We have Quick Action button. After clicking on this, we need to send email to User having information of Query object and Question object - i.e All the questions which we created for this query.

I am using HTML Template but i am getting value for Query (Parent object) but getting blank for child object

Below is the HTML Template Code:

```
Dear {!Receiving_User.Name},  


Details given below : 
Query name: {!Query__c.Name}

Questions :  {!Query__c.Question__r.Question__c}


Thanks,
```

Comment: Is Question__c a field in your question object. from the merge fields above, i can see Query > Question Object > Question object (i think you need to specify the field name from the question object here like Id or Name or Question_Name__c etc.

Comment: Yes Question__c is the field in "Object Question"

Comment: Ok, so try this. Usually related objects are referred with its plural names.

{!Query__c.Questions__r.Question__c}

Comment: No. Its not working.

Comment: Pervez, i think these links below will answer your issue. I think it is not available in Salesforce yet but you can vote 

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000324867&language=en_US&type=1

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Brk7AAC - Upvote the Idea here